# How Can I Dynamically Create Python Class Instances Using a List?

Tags: python-3.x, class, exec, eval

I am trying to understand how to dynamically create instances of a python class.

The simple example below shows how to create a class instance

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

emmy = Person("Emmy")
niels = Person("Niels")

print(emmy.name)
print(niels.name)
```

If I want to iterate through a list to create class instances, how can I dynamically execute a command the same as

```
emmy = Person("Emmy")
```

I have tried to dynamically do it with something like eval or exec method so that I can iterate through a list and be able to call the class instance name using item name from list.

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name


people = ["Emmy","Niels"]

for item in people:
    eval('item = Person(item)')

print(emmy.name)
print(niels.name)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It seems you want to have the instances  in the global environment. Could you not rather have them in a container such as a dictionary? If so, then `a = {name: Person(name) for name in people}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What would the advantage be in doing that?

Comment: That ensures that everything are contained in a container. They could be easily accessed. If you MUST have them in the global environment, then just do `globals().update(a)` after running the above code, and now you could run `Emmy.name`

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution creating a string variable to use as a command for the exec function.

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name


people = ["Emmy","Niels"]

for item in people:
    
    a = str(item) + ' = Person("' + str(item) + '")'
    exec(a)

print(Emmy.name)
print(Niels.name)
```